# Why do I need to override the collect method to use Flow in the Room DAO with a custom object?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I have a custom object called `SyncStatus` and I want to get data from a table in Room and map it to that object. I want to also use `Flow` to update the UI whenever data changes in the database.

The code works as expected, but I had to create this method in `SyncStatus`:

```
//Why I need declare this method here?
   
override suspend fun collect(collector: FlowCollector<SyncStatus>) {
    collector.emit(this)
}
```

Since I don't have much experience in Kotlin or coroutines, I would like to know why `SyncStatus` should have this method and if this is the correct way to do what I want.

Below I explain how I have organized the code, I am using the MVVM pattern and Hilt as dependency injection.

#### SyncStatus

```
class SyncStatus : Flow<SyncStatus> {
    var tableName = ""

    var versionDB = 1
    var lastUpdate = ""
    @Ignore
    var lastYearCleaned = 0

    @Ignore
    var isWorkScheduled = true

    @Ignore
    var  source: Source = Source.LOCAL 
    
    constructor()
    
    @Ignore
    constructor(lastUpdate: String, lastYearCleaned: Int) {
        this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate
        this.lastYearCleaned = lastYearCleaned
    }

    fun getAll(isNightMode: Boolean): String {
        ColorUtils.isNightMode = isNightMode
        val title = Utils.formatSubTitle(Utils.toRedFont("<b>Informe de Sincronización</b>"))
        this.tableName = Utils.formatDate(tableName, "yyyyMMdd", "yyyy-MM-dd")

        val lastYear = if (lastYearCleaned == 0) "" else String.format(
            "Los datos del año <b>%s</b> fueron limpiados.",
            Utils.toRedFont(lastYearCleaned.toString())
        )
        return String.format(
            "%s" + "%s" +
                    "Última fecha en el calendario: " +
                    "<b>%s</b> (*)" +
                    "%sÚltima sincronización: %s" +
                    "<b>%s</b>" +
                    "%s" +
                    "%s%s<small>..............%s%s(*) El calendario se sincroniza periódicamente cuando tienes conexión a internet.</small>",
            title,
            Constants.BRS,
            Utils.toRedFont(tableName),
            Constants.BRS, Constants.BR,
            Utils.toRedFont(lastUpdate),
            Constants.BRS,lastYear,
            Constants.BRS, Constants.BR, Constants.BR
        )
    }

    fun getNotWorkerMessage(isNightMode: Boolean): Spanned {
        ColorUtils.isNightMode = isNightMode
        return Utils.fromHtml(String.format(
            "<p><b>%s</b></p>La sincronización no está activada.",
            Utils.toRedFont("AVISO")
        ))
    }

    fun getWorkerMessage(): Spanned {
        return Utils.fromHtml("<p>La sincronización automática está activada.</p>")
    }

    override suspend fun collect(collector: FlowCollector<SyncStatus>) {
        collector.emit(this)
    }
}
```

#### DAO

```
@Transaction
@Query(
    "SELECT ss.lastUpdate,ss.versionDB," +
            "(SELECT max(todayDate) FROM today) tableName " +
            "FROM sync_status ss;"    )
fun lastSyncStatus(): Flow<SyncStatus>
```

#### ViewModel

```
@HiltViewModel
class SyncViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val getSyncUseCase: GetSyncUseCase,
    private val coroutineDispatcherProvider: CoroutineDispatcherProvider
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow<SyncUiState>(SyncUiState.Empty)
    val uiState: StateFlow<SyncUiState> = _uiState

    fun launchSync(syncRequest: SyncRequest) {
        _uiState.value = SyncUiState.Loading
        viewModelScope.launch(coroutineDispatcherProvider.IO()) {
            try {
                val result = getSyncUseCase.execute(syncRequest)
                _uiState.value = SyncUiState.Loaded(SyncItemUiState(result))
            } catch (error: Exception) {
                _uiState.value = SyncUiState.Error(error.message.toString())
            }
        }
    }    

    sealed class SyncUiState {
        object Empty : SyncUiState()
        object Loading : SyncUiState()
        class Loaded(val itemState: SyncItemUiState) : SyncUiState()
        class Error(val message: String) : SyncUiState()
    }
}
```

#### Fragment

```
private suspend fun onLoaded(syncItemUiState: SyncItemUiState) {
    syncItemUiState.run {
        getViewBinding().progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
        val syncResponse = syncItemUiState.syncResponse
        syncResponse.syncStatus.collect { it ->
            println(it.lastUpdate)
            println(it.tableName)
            mTextVieww.text = Utils.fromHtml(it.getAll(isNightMode()))
            if (!it.isWorkScheduled) {
                getViewBinding().include.tvBottom.text =
                    it.getNotWorkerMessage(isNightMode())
            } else {
                getViewBinding().include.tvBottom.text = it.getWorkerMessage()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### SyncResponse

```
class SyncResponse(
    _syncStatus: Flow<SyncStatus>,
    _allToday: List<Today> = emptyList()
) 
{
    var syncStatus: Flow<SyncStatus> = _syncStatus
    var allToday: List<Today> = _allToday
}
```

#### UseCase

```
class GetSyncUseCase @Inject constructor(
    private val mRepository: SyncRepository
) {
    suspend fun execute(syncRequest: SyncRequest): SyncResponse {
        return mRepository.getSync(syncRequest)
    }
}
```

#### Repository

```
interface SyncRepository {
    suspend fun getSync(syncRequest: SyncRequest): SyncResponse
}
```

#### RepositoryImpl

```
override suspend fun getSync(syncRequest: SyncRequest): SyncResponse {
    return syncFactory.create(Source.LOCAL).getSync(syncRequest)
}
```

#### Factory

```
class SyncFactory @Inject constructor(
    private val networkSyncEntityData: NetworkSyncEntityData,
    private val localSyncEntityData: LocalSyncEntityData,
    private val firebaseSyncEntityData: FirebaseSyncEntityData

) {

    fun create(source: Source): SyncEntityData {
        return when (source) {
            Source.NETWORK -> networkSyncEntityData
            Source.LOCAL  -> localSyncEntityData
            else -> firebaseSyncEntityData
        }
    }
}
```

#### `LocalSyncEntityData`

```
override suspend fun getSync(syncRequest: SyncRequest): SyncResponse {
    val se = todayDao.lastSyncStatus()
    if (syncRequest.yearToClean != 0) {
        val rowsDeleted = todayDao.deleteLastYear(syncRequest.yearToClean)
        if (rowsDeleted > 0) {
            //se.lastYearCleaned = syncRequest.yearToClean - 1
        }
    }
    se.source = Source.LOCAL
    return SyncResponse(se)
}
```

Comment: To give very short answer: *You don't*. Can you add the code of the use case? Because that's probably the place where you want it to do something

Comment: You didn't tell us what SyncStatus is, so it's hard to tell what you're doing. Did you implement Flow? You shouldn't--the docs say it is unstable for inheritance. Where did you get the idea to override `collect` and why do you think you need to?

Comment: @TheLibrarian Thanks for comment. I have added the other relevant code snippets.

Comment: @Tenfour04 `SyncStatus` is a class to get information about synchronization (of a database table) and display that data in the UI.

Comment: But it's *overriding* `collect`, so what is it subclassing or implementing that declares that function, and why is the superclass implementation any different from yours? Your whole question is about why you did something to a class that you're not showing us, making it impossible to answer.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I added the entire `SyncStatus` class to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SyncStatus class implements the Flow interface. You have to define implementations of the abstract members of an interface if you implement the interface in a non-abstract class.

(But the documentation says that you should highly prefer subclassing AbstractFlow instead of directly implementing Flow, if you want to create a Flow subtype at all, which should be extremely rare since the `flow { }` builder is very flexible.)

That all said, there is no reason your SyncStatus class should be a Flow in the first place. You're not using it as a Flow in any way. You should remove the `collect` function and the `: Flow<SyncStatus>` from the definition of your class.

---

This is how the LocalSyncEntityData function should look. You can remove `suspend` from the matching function in the interface. You don't need to suspend to transform a Flow and you often need to get Flows from outside coroutines so `suspend` is problematic.

```
override fun getSync(syncRequest: SyncRequest): Flow<SyncResponse> {
    return todayDao.lastSyncStatus()
        .onEach { se ->
            // Your code related to year to clean would go here, but I think
            // a getter function is the wrong place to do this task! 
        }
        .map { it.apply { source = Source.LOCAL } }
        .distinctUntilChanged()
}
```

Comment: If I remove `Flow` in `SyncStatus` the code does not compile. I have error at `LocalSyncEntityData`: *Type mismatch: inferred type is Flow<SyncStatus> but SyncStatus was expected*. I understand that the error occurs because the DAO method is defined like this: `fun lastSyncStatus(): Flow<SyncStatus>`. Then I using `Flow`.

Comment: I can't find the line of code you are talking about that would have an error. You absolutely should not be making your SyncStatus a Flow, so you have a conceptual problem in your design elsewhere it seems.

Comment: The error occurs in the class, `LocalSyncEntityData` in this line: `return SyncResponse(se)`.

Comment: Perhaps the correct place to collect / emit the Flow would be `LocalSyncEntityData`?  What would be the way to do it?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do. Do you want to return a single, current value of the SyncResponse, or a whole Flow of them that emits a new one every time the database is updated? If you want to return a single one like this, you can call `first()` on the returned Flow from the DAO to get just the current value. If you want to return a Flow, change the return type to a `Flow<SyncResponse>` and you can `map` the DAO flow values.

Comment: The query to the database only brings me the last row of the table, I am only interested in that row, but I also want the information to change in the UI when that data changes in the database.

Comment: Then you need to make the return type of this function a flow and you can map the DAO’s flow. And this function no longer need to be marked `suspend`.

Comment: This function has what seems to be an unrelated side effect. Why should retrieving data run a separate cleanup operation? Should this operation be run over and over as you collect the flow in your UI? It seems to me to be terrible separation of concerns.

Comment: Don't pay attention to `lastYearCleaned`, the meaning of that property here is to know the last year whose data was cleaned as information... I'm trying to implement what you suggest, but I can't get it to work. Could you give me an example of how to return the data from `LocalSyncEntityData`. I was looking at [NowInAndroid](https://github.com/android/nowinandroid/blob/e40fb7925deac9912985522378281ce0f6c9d31a/core/data/src/main/kotlin/com/google/samples/apps/nowinandroid/core/data/repository/OfflineFirstTopicsRepository.kt#L46C1-L49C1), and they use `map`, but I can't adapt it to my code.

Comment: I updated it with an example. Also, you should make SyncResponse a data class or at least give it a proper equals/hashcode implementation so you can use `distinctUntilChanged()` on it to avoid unnecessary downstream work.

Comment: Okkkk your code works fine! The function looks like this: **`override fun getSync(syncRequest: SyncRequest): Flow<SyncStatus> { return todayDao.lastSyncStatus().map { it }.distinctUntilChanged() }`** As I said, the value of lastYearCleaned here is informational, the intention here is not to clean data from the last year, but to know the status of the sync, which is saved in a table in the database. Thank you very much for your great help.

Comment: *Why should retrieving data run a separate cleanup operation? Should this operation be run over and over as you collect the flow in your UI?* Nooop. I am using a `SyncRequest` object for all sync requests. And those requests could include cleaning data from previous years. `SyncRequest` has a property `yearToClean` which will usually have a value of `0`. This value will only change on certain occasions. For example, every 3 months I will check for data from previous years, setting the value from `yearToClean` to `currentYear - 1` ...

Comment: ... Only when the value of `yearToClean` is greater than `0` will cleaning occur in the database (every 3 months). The logic at this point is: `if (syncRequest.yearToClean != 0) { todayDao.deleteLastYear(syncRequest.yearToClean) }`

Answer (score -1):

First I would separate the result of a query from the database and an object that you are using to make it clear what is purely from the database and what's not.

```
fun lastSyncStatus(): Flow<SyncStatusQueryResult>

data class SyncStatusQueryResult(
    val lastUpdate: String,
    val version: String,
    val tableName: String
)
```

Also I think you should change `SyncStatus` to `data class`

```
data class SyncStatus(
    val lastUpdate: String,
    val versionDB: Int,
    val tableName: String,
    val source: Source = Source.LOCAL,
    val lastYearCleaned: Int = 0,
    val isWorkScheduled = true
) {
    fun getAll(isNightMode: Boolean): String 

    fun getNotWorkerMessage(isNightMode: Boolean): Spanned

    fun getWorkerMessage(): Spanned
}
```

Anything that was changing member variables was

```
getAll(isNightMode: Boolean): String {
    ....
    this.tableName = Utils.formatDate(tableName, "yyyyMMdd", "yyyy-MM-dd")
    ...
```

which itself alone is suspicious and with repeated calls returns incorrect/wrong results.

And I think is the final result you were trying to achieve:

```
override suspend fun getSync(syncRequest: SyncRequest): SyncResponse {
    return SyncResponse(
        _syncStatus = todayDao.lastSyncStatus().map { result: SyncStatusQueryResult ->
            SyncStatus(
                lastUpdate = result.lastUpdate,
                versionDB = result.versionDB,
                tableName = result.tableName,
                source = Source.LOCAL,
                lastYearCleaned = 0, // Do what you have to
            )
    }
}
```

Comment: This feels like someone repeated your joke but louder.